# unable to match this regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match regular expression using python in this code.

```
CDS_REGEX = re.compile(r'\+CDS:\s*"([^"]+)",\s*(\d+)$')
cdsiMatch = allLinesMatchingPattern(self.CDS_REGEX, notificationLine)
print cdsiMatch
```

Matching String:

```
['+CDS: 24', '079119890400202306A00AA17909913764514010106115225140101061452200']
```

Please help me i am not able to find my mistake,

Comment: What is your input, and what exactly do you want to match?

Comment: And what is `allLinesMatchingPattern`?

Comment: What is the string you're matching against? The "matching string" you've shown is a list, not a string, and I'd guess it's the result of your call, not the target of it.

Answer (score -1):

1. As @Blckknght said, are you sure you really want to match that string?
2. What is `([^"]+)` supposed to match?
3. You're looking for `"` instead of `'` (you probably want `['"]`).
4. You're only checking for numbers here: `(\d+)`, but your long string clearly contains `A`'s.